# Need to Set Recordsource of Crystal Report Dynamically

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I have tried all i could and now having a log jam with no progress again.
I have about 100 crystal reports with my VB6 application and they all connect to the database using DSN (ODBC), now i want to be able to set the data source of all the crystal report from VB6 code and not using DSN anymore.
Please help, i really need it after so many days trying to find solution.

I currently call the reports using this codes :

```
Dim Appl As New CRAXDRT.Application
Dim Report As New CRAXDRT.Report
Set Report = Appl.OpenReport(App.path & "\Reports\rptBooks.rpt")
frmReport!CRViewer1.ReportSource = Report
Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
frmReport!CRViewer1.ViewReport
frmReport.Show 1
```

Now i want to set the entire recordsource from VB6 code, need help at it.